# Angular two way binding

Tags: angular, two-way-binding

Just starting with angular and I have a question.

I have a "total" section which has two individual components (see the image below):[image]

I also have a separate file that export interface "Item" as an example.

This is used in both component A and B. When there is a change in one component, I want it to be reflected on the other.

I am reading some documents online about two way binding. However I thought I would ask if anyone knows or done this before and can guide me how to achieve this.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide some relevant code to help us help you?

Comment: Sure! I will add it the current setup shortly! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to have more information on what you are trying to do ... but in general, one good way to share data between components and track changes is to use a service.

I have a blog post about it here: https://blogs.msmvps.com/deborahk/build-a-simple-angular-service-to-share-data/

And a plunker here: https://plnkr.co/edit/KT4JLmpcwGBM2xdZQeI9?p=preview

The service would look something like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable() 
export class DataService {
  serviceData: string; 
}
```